# Quotient & Remainder of $\frac{a}{bc}$

Tags: number-theory

$a, b$ and $c$ are integers:
$a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$

$b$ and $c$ are greater than zero:
$b>0 \wedge c>0$

$q$ and $r$ are the quotient and remainder of $\frac{a}{b}$:
$a=qb+r$

$t$ and $s$ are the quotient and remainder of $\frac{q}{c}$:
$q=ct+s$

I need to find the quotient and remainder of $\frac{a}{bc}$

This is what I have so far, but I'm lost, and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.
$x$ and $y$ are the quotient and remainder:

$a=bc(x)+(y)\space|\space 0\leq y<bc$

$a=bct+bs+r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right there!

$$a=bc(t)+(bs+r)$$

So $t$ is your quotient and $bs+r$ is your remainer.

Note that you need to show that it is true that $bs+r<bc$, since $bs+r$ is the supposed remainder, but we know that $r<b$ from the given information.  Thus

$$r<b\le bk, k\in\mathbb{N}$$

letting $k=c-s$ is valid since $s<c$ from the given information.  Thus

$$r<b(c-s)\Rightarrow  r<bc-bs\Rightarrow bs+r<bc$$

which is what we wanted to show.